# How to refresh dbgrid without close and open dataset in delphi?

Tags: ajax, delphi, dataset, dbgrid

I need to refresh dbgrid constantly, in real time. Close and open dataset works fine, but blink the dbgrid. What can I do to avoid this?

I'd like a solution like Ajax, that update only the necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried to use **Disable- & EnableControls**?

```
DataSet.DisableControls;
try
  DataSet.Close;
  DataSet.Open;
finally
  DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
```

Furthermore, it should be possible to just call DataSet.Refresh instead of closing and opening to get the same result.

Comment: Good advice! I had forgotten that.

Comment: If the dataset is a query, the refresh does not work. There is also another problem with this code, the dbgrid changes the scroll position. How to make dbgrid not to change it's scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my app

```
DataSet.MergeChangeLog;
DataSet.ApplyUpdates(-1);
DataSet.Refresh;
```

The above code is in an `action` named **actRefreshData**, in the `ActionManager`

When I need to use I just call it like

```
actRefreshData.Execute;
```

Hope this helps.

Hint: you can add a `Timer` and automate this

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
type THackDataSet=class(TDataSet); // a nice "hack" so we can access 
//protected members
 THackDBGrid=class(TDBGrid);

procedure {tdmdb.}refreshgrid(grid : tdbgrid);

var row, recno : integer;
    ds : tdataset;
    b : tbookmark;
begin
  Row := THackDBGrid(grid).Row;// or THackDataSet(ds).ActiveRecord

  ds := grid.datasource.dataset;

  RecNo := ds.RecNo;

  b := ds.GetBookmark;

  try
    ds.close;
    ds.Open;
  finally
    if (b<>nil) and ds.BookMarkValid(b) then
    try
     //      ds.GotoBookMark(b);
      ds.CheckBrowseMode;
      THackDataSet(ds).DoBeforeScroll;
      THackDataSet(ds).InternalGotoBookmark(b);
      if THackDataSet(ds).ActiveRecord <> Row - 1 then
      THackDataSet(ds).MoveBy(Row - THackDataSet(ds).ActiveRecord - 1);
      ds.Resync([rmExact{, rmCenter}]);
      THackDataSet(ds).DoAfterScroll;
    finally
      ds.FreeBookMark(b);
    end
    else if (recno<ds.RecordCount) and (recno<>ds.RecNo) then
    begin
      ds.First;
      ds.MoveBy(Max(0, recno-1));
    end;
  end;
end;
```