# Updating a grid after changes have been made

Tags: database, delphi, tdbgrid

Right, this is probably going to be pretty simple. I have a form that contains a grid, if you select one of the records and press 'Edit' you get taken to another form where you can edit the data attached to that record - this all works.

However upon saving it will write it to the database but will not update the aforementioned grid until I come out of my program all together and then go back in.

All I want to do is get the grid to update when exiting the other form.

I have tried opening/closing the table components, calling the 'refresh' against the query and the table.  I am connecting to the database using BDE and writing this in Rad Studio XE2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [how-to-refresh-dbgrid-without-close-and-open-dataset-in-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311007/how-to-refresh-dbgrid-without-close-and-open-dataset-in-delphi) if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem

```
Table1.Active := False;  
Table1.Active := True;
```

for a TTable and

```
TQuery1.Active := False;
TQuery1.active := True;
```

for a TQuery